# reactJs App js - passing incoming data as props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

How do I pass data from the app.js file as json to the app.js file as props. I want to display the incoming data as json in the whole project.

**I want to pass the incoming data as props.**

**{id: 1, first_name: "", last_name: "", profile: {…}}
  {id: 1, userKey: "0245abb9-2837-4f37-ae02-9be1b88887ef", gsmNo: "05442221111", phone: ""}**

Thank you from now

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import './App.scss';
import {updateCustomer} from "../components/helpers/actions/customerActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-3 text-center">Loading...</div>;

// Containers
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import('../containers/DefaultLayout'));

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('../views/Pages/Login'));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import('../views/Pages/Register'));
const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import('../views/Pages/Page404'));
const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import('../views/Pages/Page500'));


class App extends Component {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      profile_items: [ ]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onUpdateCustomer({ID: "-1", customerKey: "-1"});

    console.log("app.js");

        return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/me',
           {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("id_token")}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
            })
            .then((response) => response.json() )
            .then((responseData) => {
              console.log(responseData);
              this.setState({
                profile_items: responseData
              });
              //console.log(this.state.profile_items)
                  return responseData;
            })
            .catch(error => console.warn(error));

  }

  render() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
            <Switch >
              <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
              <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props =>  <DefaultLayout {...props}/>} />
            </Switch>
          </React.Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return state;
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onUpdateCustomer: updateCustomer,
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (App );
```

Comment: Can you explain this, pass data  from app.js file as json to the app.js file as props? or you mean you want to pass data from app.js to another component as props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HOC to pass props into Lazy Component. With my option, I think it work.
Create HOC:

```
const LazyHOC = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Component {...rest} />
)
```

import your component:

```
const ComponentExample = React.lazy(() => import('./components/ComponentExample'));
```

Wrap Component with HOC:

```
const LazyComponentExample = props => <LazyHOC component={ComponentExample} {...props}/>
```

And you can pass props like this:

```
<React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
   <Switch >
      <Route 
         exact path="/login" 
         name="Component example" 
         render={<LazyComponentExample props={...} />} />
   </Switch>
</React.Suspense>
```